# Automatic formatting in web page content

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have content stored as raw text in a database that I show in a HTML table on a web site.  In the content people refer to numbers and i want to have those numbers automatically become links

For example, in a field I might have

```
This description is for driving a car.  The manual refers to ABC:25920 and is very durable.
```

In this case above I want ABC:2590 to actually be an HTML link that translates to this HTML

```
<a href='www.mysite.com/parts/25920'>ABC:25920</a>
```

What is the best way of doing this. Some kind of find and replace? Is there some other pattern matching / regex solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear precisely what format the numbers have.  If the rule is that anything which consists of capital letters, a colon, and a number *n* should be turned into the link `www.mysite.com/parts/n`, then you can use a regex-based find-and-replace solution.  You would want to look for the regex `[A-Z]+:(\d+)`.  What this says is "find one or more capital letters, a colon, and (capturing them) find one or more digits".  You then want to replace this with `<a href='www.mysiste.com/parts/$1'>$0</a>`; in this case, `$1` refers back to the capturing group (that is, the digits), and `$0` refers to the whole match.  I don't know C#, but I think this would look like

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// ...
string result = Regex.replace( getTextFromDatabase()
                             , @"[A-Z]+:(\d+)"
                             , "<a href='www.mysiste.com/parts/$1'>$0</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:
Part number is always 5 digits
Part identifier is three alpha characters.

```
static string RegexLinkify(string text)
{ 
    string pattern = @"(?<alphaCode>[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]):(?<partNumber>\d{5})";
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match matches = r.Match(text);
    string alphaCode = matches.Groups["alphaCode"].Value.ToString();
    string partNumber = matches.Groups["partNumber"].Value.ToString();
    string url = "<a href='www.mysite.com/parts/{0}'>{1}:{0}</a>";
    url = string.Format(url, alphaCode, partNumber);
    return url;

}
```

You can pass the data from the model to this helper method.